# PHP class_implements class does not exist

Tags: php, paysafe

I am implementing a payment system with the php paysafe SDK (https://github.com/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php)

> class_implements(): Class Refund does not exist and could not be loaded

I am able to create the class Refund like this `$r = new Refund()` but not with `class_implements()`.

The developers of the paysafe SDK are under windows and I am on ubuntu, does that can make a difference with `class_implements()`?

```
$refunds = $this->client->cardPaymentService()->getRefunds(new Refund(array('id' => $p->refund_num)));// class exist
$r = new Refund(); // class exist
class_implements("Refund"); // class_implements(): Class Refund does not exist and could not be loaded
$test = new Pagerator($this->client, $refunds , "Refund"); // class_implements(): Class Refund does not exist and could not be loaded

public function __construct(\Paysafe\PaysafeApiClient $client, $data, $className)
    {
        if (!in_array('Paysafe\Pageable', class_implements($className))) {
            throw new PaysafeException("$className does not implement \Paysafe\Pageable");
        }

        $this->client = $client;

        $this->className = $className;
        $this->arrayKey = call_user_func($className . '::getPageableArrayKey');
        $this->position = 0;

        $this->parseResponse($data);
    }
```

Comment: That's odd, does this work: `class_implements($r);`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Its working with class_implements($r)... but I will have to update the constructor to instantiate a class from a variable and I will need the right namespace for each class

Answer (score 2):

Calling class_implements with a non-loadable class name or a non-object results in a warning.

```
class_implements("Refund"); // class_implements(): Class Refund does not exist and could not be loaded
```

If you check the Paysafe library and go into the object definition.

https://github.com/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php/blob/master/source/paysafe/CardPayments/Refund.php

You will see that there is no autoload function. You might have to hardcode it yourself when importing the library to support this feature.

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
   require_once $class_name . '.php';
}
```

We just released TAG 1.03 that fixed some autoloading issues for some if you are still having the problem.

https://github.com/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php/commits/master

You could also use Packagist repo : https://packagist.org/packages/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php

Comment: there is already a custom __autoload https://github.com/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php/blob/master/source/paysafe.php

Comment: You are right. Did you actually hit that function __PaysafeAutoloader when you debug?

Comment: yeah I enter inside __PaysafeAutoloader and I can see that CardPayments/Refund.php is called. I would not be able to use the other functions of __PaysafeAutoloader was not working

Comment: This might be stupid but did you try with single quote? class_implements('Refund')

Comment: I guess you also use composer since you go inside the function... https://github.com/paysafegroup/paysafe_sdk_php/blob/master/composer.json

Answer (score 0):

`class_implements` is not available in versions prior to 5.1.0 - please verify which version of PHP your server is running.

Comment: I am on PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20